# How to include a variable between strings in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, export-to-excel

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);    
var    
   xlap,xlbook,xlsheet:variant;
   y:integer;
begin
   xlap:=createoleobject('excel.application');
   xlbook:=xlap.workbooks.add;
   xlap.visible:=true;
   xlsheet:=xlbook.worksheets.add;

   for y:=1 to 50 do
   begin 
    xlsheet.cells[y,2].value:= concat('=IF(A',y,'>6,"Good","Bad")')
    inc(y);
  end;
end;
```

That's my code to make an Excel through Delphi. I want to input the IF formula into column B of the Excel, but there is error when I use the `concat('=IF(A',y,'>6,"Good","Bad")')`.

May be I need another way to include y between those strings.

Any suggestion? Thanks before

Comment: Maybe IntToStr(y)? Delphi is strongly typed... you can't mix strings and integers like that.

Comment: Which delphi unit has a `concat` function? And if the complete error text is not **top secert** please add this to your question

Comment: Do you mean this?    xlsheet.cells[y,2].value:= '=IF(A',IntToStr(y),'>6,"Good","Bad")'

Comment: the error message: [Error] USimpanMysql.pas(190): '.' expected but ';' found.                this is when I use     xlsheet.cells[y,2].value:= concat('=IF(A',y,'>6,"Good","Bad")')

Comment: @SirRufo, [`Concat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Concat) is a magic function, it's been in the language since the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Mr Frazz, Sir Rufo, LU RD anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Tony's answer about `Format`, here are a couple of other approaches. (`Format` is great if you have mixed types or many values, but it carries some overhead that might not be needed.)

You can concatenate strings with a simple `+` - in fact, the [Concat documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Concat) says it does the same thing but is faster:

```
Temp := 'ing';
Str := 'Test' +  Temp;   // Str = 'Testing'
```

As your `y` variable is an integer, you'll need to convert it to a string first (note you don't need to `Inc(y);`, as the loop will do that already - it's automatically incremented from the starting value to the ending value on each pass through the loop):

```
for y:=1 to 50 do
begin 
  xlsheet.cells[y,2].value:= '=IF(A' + IntToStr(y) + '>6,"Good","Bad")';
end;
```

Comment: It works. Thanks very much Mr Ken White. But there is no comma between A and '

Comment: @Ray: Yes, I caught that and fixed it. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Delphi has a [format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format) statement bit like sprintf printf in c, well nearly

```
xlsheet.cells[y,2].value:= format('=IF(A%d>6,"Good", "Bad")',[y])
```

%d is a place holder for an int. Look it up for loads of other stuff.
NB the variables you want to interpolate are assed in an array.

Comment: It works. Thanks so much Mr Tony. By the way, there is no comma between A and %d